# Is it possible to test init.d script inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, init.d

I need test some init.d script to check if it can be executed as expected during system reboot process. Is it possible to use a docker container to test it? In another word, can system reboot process be simulated by restarting a docker container?

Comment: any process that is mentioned in `CMD` will execute whenever you restart your container. like `docker stop my_container` and then `docker start my_container`, you do need to put them in `init.d`

Comment: Docker containers don’t generally run init systems or any of the system daemons that a full system would have.  A virtual machine would be a much better match for this use case.

Comment: @DavidMaze, that makes sense. Thanks.